# How do I insert yesterdays date instead of today?

Tags: datetime

I usually generate a report for the previous day (as I imagine isn't all too uncommon) and so I'd like to date it with yesterday's date instead of today. Currently I have:

```
\title{foo}
\date{\today}
```

But I can't seem to find a `\yesterday` or anything beyond simple formatting in packages like `datetime` - is there a simple way to get this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's an old but working package: `advdate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{advdate}
\title{foo}
\date{\AdvanceDate[-1]\today}  % Go back one day

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Today is \today\ but yesterday was {\AdvanceDate[-1]\today}

but we are still \today



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

With `\yesterday` and `\tomorrow` commands (note the internal grouping)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{advdate}

\newcommand{\yesterday}{{\AdvanceDate[-1]\today}}

\newcommand{\tomorrow}{{\AdvanceDate[1]\today}}

\title{foo}
\date{\yesterday}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent Today is \today\ but yesterday was \yesterday, tomorrow will be \tomorrow,
but we are still on \today.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I tried googling for how to do this and was surprised not to find something given how common it probably is to do this.

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass{article}
\advance\day by -1
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

[image]

(created on October 14, 2015)

(But it won't work on the first of a month ... so advdate or a similar package from http://www.ctan.org/topic/date-time is better ;-))

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is to use [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) with the `calc` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}

\title{Sample}
\author{Me}
\date{\DTMdate{\year-\month-\day+-1}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh the overloaded `-` is so nicely confusing :-)

Comment: @yo' Yes, I forgot on my first attempt that I needed the `+` before `-1`. That's the `pgfcalendar` syntax which `datetime2-calc` uses behind the scenes :-)